# How can I add letters in a sentence?

Tags: c++

I've asked to write code that gets a char array(sentence), if the there is an 'i' in the sentence I need to add the letter 'b' the letter 'i' again like this example:

pig -> pibig

I tried to use string.h functions but I didn't succeed to make it right.

Comment: Show the sample code of what you have tried and what doesn't work

Comment: In C++ stay away from `string.h` if you can help it and use `std::string` from `<string>` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::string` in `string` header file, and `std::string::insert` whenever you need to insert a char in string:

```cpp
std::string  my_string = "my satringa";

for (size_t i = 0; i < my_string.length(); ++i)
{
  if (my_string.at(i) == 'a')
  {
    my_string.insert(i + 1, "b");
  }
}

std::clog << my_string << std::endl;
```

#### Output:

```sh
> my sabtringab
```

If you are forced to use C-style strings, don't worry do all of your operations on `std::string` and then take the underlying stored string with `std::string::c_str()` as a C-style string (and don't forget to take a copy).